# Firestore: Delete document from a collection in firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I delete a specific document within a collection on the firestore using react?

I looked here and on google but I didn't find anything intrinsically related.

I'm just managing to delete the document with index [0] from my collection.

this.state.idDoc recives all id documents.

If I just pass the .doc(idDoc) I get the following error:

**FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: an array**

What am I doing wrong? any help is welcome.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     idDoc: = [],
    }

delete = () => {
      let idDoc = this.state.idDoc;
      firebase.firestore().collection("newPost").doc(idDoc[0]).delete()
      .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
      }).catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
      });
    }
```

html button

```
<div>
     <button id="PostDelete" onClick={this.delete}> <ion-icon name="ellipsis-horizontal-sharp"> </ion-icon> </button> 
</div>
```

Comment: You have to pass the id of the document to delete

Comment: I do this, but I can only get index [0] from the array where my document ids are, so I can only delete index 0 from the array. when I have many posts within that collection I will not be able to delete others except the index document [0]. I wanted to learn how to do it in a dynamic way, without having to create several functions to delete each index of the array.

Comment: The error says you are passing an array instead of string,to delete each document you need to iterate over the array

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. I can get all the document ids but I can't find a way for my post deletion function to identify which post is being deleted specifically. every time I run my function, it only deletes the first document created in the collection.

Comment: already tested to return the ids to a string, but still deleting only the first document created, I can't find a way to recognize which document is being deleted by the id.

if i remove the index [0] from idDoc, i get an error from firebase saying that they only accept arguments in .doc () of type string

Answer (score 0):

The id you are passing to the collection is in a invalid format.

Comment: Please consider adding more information regarding why exactly id is in an invalid format & what would be valid format in that case.